# sms broadcast receiver not call in api 26 until re-run application

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms

I have an application with SMS broadcast receiver , everything is working good but in android android api 26 after get `android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS` permission from user it's still has not permission until app restart at least one time . how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I requested 4 dangerous permission in string array at same time . by placing sms permissions at first and second position of array my problem resolved